# Can't uninstall Blender? (windows 10)

Tags: windows

I downloaded Blender for something (relatively) small, but the program was much more than I needed (which I guess is a positive, but I'll never use a good deal of it) and decided to uninstall (save space) However, the program wont leave my computer. After the normal uninstall route failed to work, I tried removing the files manually - Even with all of them scrubbed clean, it still shows that Blender is installed on my PC, but I can't access, modify, or remove it. Any way to help, or have I completely broken it?

Comment: This is more a question about Windows 10 maintenance. [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) can force remove entries from the installed programs list